# pick up custom views in UIView hierarchy

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview-hierarchy

There is a situation that should select all custom view(not system view type such as UILabel or UIButton etc.) like XXButton or XXView. How can I iterate a UIView's subviews to figure out all the custom views? In other words, how to distinguish between unknown class custom views and Apple system views?

Comment: where did these custom views come from and why do you need them? interrogating the view hierarchy is probably not the correct solution...

Comment: @Wain customviews maybe from a bundle by third-party or whatever

Comment: then you have a problem because you don't know how to tell the difference between Apple public, Apple private, random 3rd party and your own view classes...

Comment: `-isMemberOfClass:` method might help on you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following,

```
for viw in self.view.subviews
{
if viw.classForCoder == yourCustomViewClass
{
     // do your required operation
}
}
```

1. In above case first we have used for in loop to iterate on all sub views of particular view.
2. Then we have checked the class for the view from the subview's array

Comment: thank for the answer, but actually I did not know the customView class or there is a lot of custom views in different class

Comment: use this block where ever you need

Comment: just replace the custom calss name

Comment: what is your final aim after retrieving the custom views

Answer (score 0):

When you created a `XXButton` or `XXView`, they basically inherited from the `UIButton` and `UIView` respectively. Thus you have to explicitly checks for your custom class only.

```
//Loop through all the views in your superview.
for(UIView *anyView in self.view.subviews) {

    if([anyView isKindOfClass:[XXButton class]]) {

        // It's a XXButton. Need to cast it.
        XXButton *btn = (XXButton *)anyView;

    } else if([anyView isKindOfClass:[XXView class]]) {

        // It's a XXView. Need to cast it.
        XXView *view = (XXView *)anyView;

    }

    // You can multiple else if conditions for your custom UI classes.
}
```